# Xcode 8 constraints don't work correctly

Tags: xcode

I created my app in Xcode 8, using swift. When I add missing constraints and test it goes bananas. As you can imagine this is a disaster, what is the best way to get my app to fit multiple screen sizes and orientations?

Comment: I'm afraid "it goes bananas" is not a good error description. :) This is pretty common - probably anyone starting work on that platform will experience this at first. It's too broad for a Stack Overflow question though. There is good documentation for it out there, see e. g. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, sorry for the nonspecifics. It seemed the most apt description, when I add missing constraints for the whole view controller. All my buttons do not display correctly, pretty much my whole interface messes up.

Comment: I know the feeling. No way around systematically working to understand how it works, though. (A *specific* problem that you have might work as a Stack Overflow question - but you'll have to be more specific about what it is.) Personally, I discovered React Native halfway into learning Swift, and it looks like I'm going to stick with it - it has a much more intuitive positioning system, way more understandable at least to this web developer. (Of course, it is always immensely useful to know your way around Swift and XCode either way).

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. Fixed the issue, I just had to remove them all and add constraints manually one by one. Long process!